# How do you make an excel formula that uses the Index and Match function to show multiple responses?

Tags: indexing, excel-formula, match

I have an excel spreadsheet that has the name of a bunch of projects in one column (B) and the binder number that the projects reside in, in column (C). There are some duplicate project names in the project column (B) because the same project is in multiple binders. My problem is that the code I am using now only comes back with the first binder number for a project and will not show the second binder number when there are duplicates of the same project. Is there a way to fix my formula to show both binder numbers. Here is my formula  `=INDEX(C4:C401,MATCH(B2,B4:B401,FALSE),1)`Please look at the image of my spreadsheet for help. [image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkpuA.jpg

Comment: We dont see the image of your spreadsheet.

Comment: Just fixed it. Thanks for tell me!

Comment: A screenshot in its true form. :D